# How to add a list of values into a column in a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `books` and a column called `price`. How can I update all the values in that column? Below is the query that I wrote.

```
INSERT INTO `books`(`price`)
VALUES (176.00,
        337.00,
        234.00,
        180.00,
        135.00,
        72.00,
        72.00,
        81.00,
        135.00,
        113.00,
        162.00);
```

This is currently how y table looks.

```
| Book ID | Price |
|---------|-------|
| a       |       |
| b       |       |
| c       |       |
| d       |       |
```

This is how i want it to look.

```
| Book ID | Price |
|---------|-------|
| a       | 12    |
| b       | 13    |
| c       | 14    |
| d       | 15    |
```

Can anyone suggest how I should modify the query? I can delete the existing column and create a new one also.

Comment: Use `INSERT` to insert new rows into the table, use `UPDATE` to update existing rows.

Comment: Edit your question and add some sample table data, and then show us the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please try answering now?

Comment: One solution is to copy the book ids inside an excel sheet, paste the prices in the next column and generate a query for each row such as `UPDATE books SET price = 12 WHERE book_id = 'a'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
INSERT INTO `books`(`price`) VALUES (176.00), 
(337.00), (234.00), (180.00), (135.00), (72.00), (72.00), (81.00), (135.00), (113.00), (162.00);
```

If you want to update, you also need id values at the source data. If you have id too can use this method.

```
CREATE TABLE `temp`(id int, `price` decimal(18,2));

INSERT INTO `temp`(`id`, `price`) VALUES 
(1, 176.00), 
(2, 337.00), 
(3, 234.00), 
(4, 180.00), 
(5, 135.00), 
(6, 72.00), 
(7, 72.00), 
(8, 81.00), 
(9, 135.00), 
(10, 113.00), 
(11, 162.00);


UPDATE `books` 
INNER JOIN `temp` ON `books`.`id` =  `temp`.id
SET `books`.`price` = `temp`.`price`;


INSERT INTO `books`(`price`)
SELECT  `price` FROM `temp` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `books`.`id` =  `temp`.`id`);
```

Comment: With the query suggested above, new records are being created with the existing records left empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution for your problem :

Table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE books(price DECIMAL(20,6)) #ENGINE=MyISAM;


INSERT INTO `books`(`price`)
VALUES (176.00), (337.00), (234.00), (180.00), (135.00), (72.00), (72.00), (81.00), (135.00), (113.00), (162.00);


SELECT *
FROM books;
```

and you can also refer [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88d6d6b/1).

I hope it will help.